# HiveQL - join multi-level subtotals to existing table

Tags: sql, hiveql

My goal is to determine the size of various organizations at various levels. Let's assume we have three organisations 'A', 'B', and 'C', each consisting of multiple department and having a further subdivision in teams with members., as outlined below:

```
Org.    Dep.    Tm. Member
A       1       I   name1
A       1       I   name2
A       1       I   name3
A       1       II  name4
A       2       I   name5
A       2       I   name6
B       1       I   name7
B       1       II  name8
B       1       II  name9
B       1       II  name10
B       2       I   name11
B       2       I   name12
B       2       II  name13
B       2       II  name14
B       2       III name15
B       2       III name16
C       1       I   name17
C       1       I   name18
C       1       I   name19
C       1       I   name20
C       1       I   name21
```

Now, I'd like to know for each member how large their respective Org., Dep. and Tm. are, like this:

```
Org.    Dep.    Tm. Member  org dep tm
A       1       I   name1   6   4   3
A       1       I   name2   6   4   3
A       1       I   name3   6   4   3
A       1       II  name4   6   4   1
A       2       I   name5   6   2   2
A       2       I   name6   6   2   2
B       1       I   name7   10  4   1
B       1       II  name8   10  4   3
B       1       II  name9   10  4   3
B       1       II  name10  10  4   3
B       2       I   name11  10  6   2
B       2       I   name12  10  6   2
B       2       II  name13  10  6   2
B       2       II  name14  10  6   2
B       2       III name15  10  6   2
B       2       III name16  10  6   2
C       1       I   name17  5   5   5
C       1       I   name18  5   5   5
C       1       I   name19  5   5   5
C       1       I   name20  5   5   5
C       1       I   name21  5   5   5
```

My original idea was to do this with multiple LEFT JOINS to aggregate the different levels, but this scales very poorly as you need a new join for every aggregation level. Is there a way to do this efficiently in a single statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select org, dep, tm,
       count(*) over (partition by org) as org_cnt,
       count(*) over (partition by org, dep) as dep_cnt,
       count(*) over (partition by org, dep, tm) as tm_cnt
from t;
```

The columns are hierarchical so `dep` and `tm` need the higher levels of the hierarchy.

EDIT:

If Hive doesn't support `count(distinct)` and you need it, then you can do:

```
select org, dep, tm,
       sum(case when seqnum_o = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by org) as org_cnt,
       sum(case when seqnum_od = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by org, dep) as dep_cnt,
       sum(case when seqnum_odt = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by org, dep, tm) as tm_cnt
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over partition by org, memberid order by org) as seqnum_o,
             row_number() over partition by org, dep, memberid order by org) as seqnum_od,
             row_number() over partition by org, dep, tm, memberid order by org) as seqnum_odt
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: this works when every entry is unique, do you know if there's also a way to do `count(distinct Member)`? I'm getting errors because distinct only works with a group by statement...